# Can I import my emails from Outlook 2010 to the Windows 8 mail app?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, email, microsoft-outlook-2010, import

I'm getting ready to transfer everything to my new laptop which I am getting for Christmas. I am moving from Windows 7 to Windows 8.1 and I would have  liked to try and get the grips with the Mail app that is built into the new operating system. However, I have a lot of emails which I would like to keep.

Is it possible to import my Outlook 2010 PST file into the Windows 8 Mail app or something? If so, how?

Comment: the mail app doesn't support PST. You can install Outlook 2010 in Win8, too.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Well that's a shame. Is there a third party application that will allow me to do this? I know I could install Outlook 2010 but I'd have preferred to use the Mail app.